# How to display and link two sql tables?

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to display genres from a "Genre" Table in SQL to my main table
I found a way to do it with one item but I cannot find a way to do it with multiple genres

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("ShowInformation - Copy.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''SELECT name, GenreName, GenreName, Synopsis, EPCount, AgeRating, Score, Studio, Popularity
  FROM Genres AS g
  JOIN Animes AS a
    ON a.GenreID1 AND a.GenreID2 = g.ID;''')
item = c.fetchall()
print (item[0])
print (item)
```

I got an error from this and I don't know how to fix it.

My SQL database:
[image]
[image]

Comment: A [View](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm) may suite your needs.

Comment: Isn't View just the same as SQL statement. Also, even if it is different, I don't think I can use it since I'm using PYQt5 to display the information from the SQL statement

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Try `ON g.ID IN (a.GenreID1, a.GenreID2)`.

Comment: View = "
Structure data in a way that users or classes of users find natural or intuitive.
Restrict access to the data such that a user can only see limited data instead of a complete table.
Summarize data from various tables, which can be used to generate reports.
"

What are you trying to accomplish right now?

Comment: This kind of work but duplicates the lines. What I want are the Genre IDs to be turned into the GenreName. I thought foreign keys automatically does that.

Comment: Do one LEFT JOIN for each genre. (To avoid multiple rows.)

Comment: That didn't work either. Now it displays all the genres instead of only displaying the show with the IDs being replaced for the names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` for each genre:

```
SELECT a.*, g1.GenreName, g2.GenreName, ...
FROM Animes AS a
LEFT JOIN Genres AS g1 ON a.GenreID1 = g1.ID
LEFT JOIN Genres AS g2 ON a.GenreID2 = g2.ID
...
```

Comment: This works however, the IDs are still being displayed. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Simply only include the wanted columns in the SELECT list, e.g. SELECT a.name, g1.GenreName, g2.GenreName, a.Synopsis etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your ON clause is a bit odd looking for me. You seem to have missed part of the statement on the left of the AND. Did you mean to put in the below?

```
ON a.GenreID1 = g.ID AND a.GenreID2 = g.ID
```

Sharing the error message always helps people help you.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work

What I'm trying to do is get rid of the "GenreIDs" for the actual genres. So instead of the ID numbers displaying, I want to genres to display